# Xcode 6 won't start (OS X 10.9.4)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode6

Recently, within the last few days, whenever I try to open Xcode6-Beta2 on my 2013 11" MacBook Air running OS X 10.9.4, I get a problem report and Xcode won't run. I tried uninstalling Xcode 6 (by dragging it to the trash can) and reinstalling it, and I tried a computer restart - neither has solved the problem.

[image]

My best guess is that it's related to OS X 10.9.4 - I hadn't really touched Xcode in a week or so, and the only major thing I had done on my machine in the last week was to update to 10.9.4. But I'm not really sure. Has anyone else seen this error?

Comment: Upgrade to the latest beta.

Comment: I did so. Did not help.

Comment: Launch Xcode in terminal using SUDO (see post below)

Comment: I have had Xcode start up slowly the first time on Xcode 5.1.1, 6.0.1, and 6.1 beta 2.  With OS X version 10.9.5, I get a dialog that says that security is verifying the apps.  It seems to me that Gatekeeper is slowing down in 10.9.4 and in 10.9.5, and that some configurations weren't even showing the progress dialog at all.

Answer (score 41):

XCode 6 GM wasn't opening for me either, no matter how long I waited.  I've seen this behavior before and it's usually due to a program needing ROOT access to complete or delete something, but for some reason isn't prompting you.

The workaround is launching Xcode by command line via **SUDO** (as Superuser/Root):

```
sudo open --new /Applications/Xcode.app
```

After it opens you may close it and re-launch it normally from that point forward.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is quite close to how I got it working, the only difference is that after launching with sudo it was still not responding. However after relaunching again normally afterwards it worked (after the quitting the sudo launch). Apple is so rich, they could save hours of global programmer time by testing their releases properly.

Comment: SkillM2 if the SUDO method doesn't appear to be working (although I gather from your response, it did), there are two additional steps you should perform. 1) Open Disk Utility and run Verify Disk, if that checks out, then 2) From Disk Utility run Repair (not Verify) Permissions.  Once this is done, reboot (although usually not necessary, but recommended for completeness). Once logged back on, try the SUDO solution. Hard drive and/or permission corruption can and does lead to odd behavior.

Comment: It sort of did work, just slightly differently in my case than described, so the instance that opened up sudo was still not responding but after that any time I opened it was fine. I think you are correct that it needed root access to complete something.

Comment: Experienced the exact same as Skill M2. First start with `sudo`, appears to not do anything. But then start again with your account and this finally then worked!. Thanks guys! (OS X 10.10 / Xcode 6.1)

Comment: This worked for me. Was having issues with Xcode 6.1 on Yosemite.

Answer (score 13):

Try running the Xcode binary directly instead of using LSS.

From the CLI:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

If something is wrong it will give you way more useful output.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. And no errors, no need to sudo.

Answer (score 9):

On my quite new Macbook Pro with plenty of memory and SSD, it took ages to start for the first time. So my suggestion would be to wait a little bit more and see if it does start. My first startup took aprox. 4 minutes or something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - this question was related to beta 2, and has long since been fixed. :) Also, the first Xcode start-up is always slow because it's being checked by Gatekeeper, see: http://furbo.org/2014/09/03/xcode-vs-gatekeeper/ However, in my case, it wasn't taking a long time to start - the problem report would open and then it would cease trying to start up at all. It was derricky's solution above which solved it for me.

Comment: I have a 2 1/2 year old MBP running 10.9.4. It took XCode 10 minutes to start after upgrading to XCode6 seed. The XCode icon in the dock jumped for about 60 seconds then the icon was dormant until it finally launched with new EULAs.

Comment: Installing Xcode 6 GM Seed (6A313) over Xcode 5.1 on my 2.5 year old MBP running 10.9.4 I had the same experience as Gary. But it eventually started.

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem after updating to 10.9.4.

I managed to get Xcode starting again by removing the **PlugInKit.framework** from the /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks folder

*(Of course, it is a good idea to back up the framework instead of simply deleting it in case you need it later)*

**Updated Oct 9**

**Note:** This was a solution to work around a XCode launch issue related to a "Symbol not found" error within the **PlugInKit.framework** while XCode 6 was still in Beta 2/3. This is probably not relevant any more now that XCode 6 is official.

Comment: I posted the correct answer below, using SUDO. This (deleting PluginKit.framework) SHOULD NOT be the correct answer, although it may have worked, you should always attempt to launch a fresh install of Xcode (should it be giving you grief) under Terminal using SUDO. Anything the installer or app needs to complete, correct or delete would be handled by this.

Comment: Glad to have seen Jason's comment.  deleting folders only served to render my laptop un-bootable.

Comment: @TomCheney but it's working anyway, and I don't know how to solve it another way. Don't know why I didn't found this post earlier - I spent a night for trying fix it - took Time Machine month-ago backup twice, reinstall OS X. For temporary solution - it's ok. Thank you, @derricky!

Comment: For the recent commenters: this was a problem related to Time Machine back-ups and Xcode6-Beta2 two months ago. Not the Xcode 6 GM. derricky's solution was correct for the problem at the time. I don't necessarily advise trying this for Xcode 6 GM.

Comment: UberJason But the question mentions nothing about Time Machine. I might also express that this "xcode wont start" problem isn't exclusive to Xcode 6 (in beta or golden master) but previous vers too. I ran into this prob for example with XCode 4+5. And I have to express (if not outright exclaim) that one should NEVER remove Plugin.framework. If you think that's the problem, chances are there are deeper issues with your OS and running the proper diags or a fresh OS install would be better solut. Please UNCHECK this as the answer, even if you found it helped. It is REMARKABLY bad advice!

Comment: Well, okay. You're right that I never mentioned Time Machine in my question; that was a commonality I had with a few other people who were having the same problem. I also noticed that PluginKit.framework was something that my Mac with this problem had which my other Mac without this problem did not have (it didn't seem to exist there at all). But I'll agree with you that blindly removing frameworks is probably not a robust solution, so I've unchecked this answer.

Comment: Worked for me.  After XCode launches it asks for root privileges, so clearly it's trying to clean up some stuff, as suspected elsewhere.  It just crashes before it even gets there.

Comment: Well I agree this is a bad idea (hence I had a foot note that ask you to do a backup of the PluginKit.framework folder. This issue came up way back when Xcode was still in beta2/3. I am sure things have changed now that you are on GM, or even official, release. This solution obviously was meant to be a solution for those who encounters it during the beta phase.

Comment: Oh and just one more comment. I was not using Time Machine at all, so this issue was not related to Time Machine.

Answer (score 2):

I was using Xcode6-Beta3 fine up until today when I updated to 10.9.4. Now I get the same error, the interesting part of which is:

> Application Specific Information:
>   dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
>
> Dyld Error Message:
>     Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_LSApplicationProxy
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PlugInKit.framework/Versions/A/PlugInKit
>     Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
>    in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PlugInKit.framework/Versions/A/PlugInKit

I have filed a bug with Apple regarding this issue.

Comment: Yep, that is the exact same error I have! And yet, strange that I haven't found anyone else who's had this problem...

Comment: UberJason Is that because you deleted PluginKit.framework as you indicated you did above (where you said removing that work in launching Xcode)? Please read my comment in that (wrong) answer.

Comment: No, this was part of the error where Xcode 6 beta 2 was refusing to launch.

Comment: Will you provide us with a bug ID.  The more people that report a problem, the higher priority Apple will give it.

Comment: This was the original error we saw when Xcode refused to start. The solution I mentioned work around this particular error. I am guessing Apple forgot to include an updated version of the PluginKit along with their earlier Xcode beta release.