# Xcode doesn't launch: "Xcode quit unexpectedly"

Tags: xcode, macos

I got a new Macbook Pro(second hand,formatted and wiped clean) and tried installing Xcode on it. But for some reason, it just doesn't launch after installation. It gives the error "Xcode quit unexpectedly" and "Click Reopen to launch it again", but when I click Reopen, I get the same error box again (Screenshot below).

[image]

I went through similar questions and [tried launching Xcode through the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567433/xcode-6-wont-start-os-x-10-9-4) as described in this answer, but through this process, the Xcode icon briefly starts up in the dock, and disappears after 3 seconds, with no error message on the terminal at all.

Please help.

EDIT:

Including part of crash report:

```
Process:               Xcode [846]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.3.2 (7718)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7718000000000000~2
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812404257
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [846]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-05-21 22:30:08.322 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D131)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        35E6816B-554F-7731-9409-E1CA9F1808B3

Sleep/Wake UUID:       86FF739A-E75B-4EA9-9BC2-25505518A562

Time Awake Since Boot: 750 seconds
Time Since Wake:       410 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fff560ea000

VM Regions Near 0x7fff560ea000:
    Stack                  00007fff558ea000-00007fff560ea000 [ 8192K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 0
--> 
    __TEXT                 00007fff6ddea000-00007fff6de21000 [  220K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D2105

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b87b670 __CFUniCharPrioritySort + 32
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b86380b CFStringNormalize + 2715
2   ???                             0x000000010cc01a00 0 + 4508883456
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b8535f5 parseQuotedPlistString + 1029
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b852363 parsePlistObject + 419
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b852df4 parsePlistDictContent + 692
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b85237c parsePlistObject + 444
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b852df4 parsePlistDictContent + 692
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b85237c parsePlistObject + 444
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b852882 parsePlistObject + 1730
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b851f1e __CFCreateOldStylePropertyListOrStringsFile + 638
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b7ceee0 _CFPropertyListCreateFromUTF8Data + 2240
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b8cfa2e _CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLStringError + 270
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b8cfaa8 _CFPropertyListCreateFromXMLString + 88
14  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9537137e -[NSString(NSExtendedStringPropertyListParsing) propertyList] + 59
15  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000109b39059 +[DVTSourceSpecification registerSpecificationProxiesFromPropertyListsInDirectory:recursively:inBundle:] + 1306
16  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000109b38afb +[DVTSourceSpecification registerSpecificationProxiesFromPropertyListsInDirectory:recursively:] + 75
17  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000109b3867b +[DVTSourceSpecification searchForAndRegisterAllAvailableSpecifications] + 1243
18  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x000000010a7711cb IDEInitialize + 988
19  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010ad5078c -[IDEApplicationController applicationWillFinishLaunching:] + 710
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b8c745c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
21  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8b7b7634 _CFXNotificationPost + 3140
22  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff952809d1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
23  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x0000000109cc9918 -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 162
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9299ef57 -[NSApplication finishLaunching] + 440
25  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010a271952 -[DVTApplication finishLaunching] + 149
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9299ea21 -[NSApplication run] + 128
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9291b354 NSApplicationMain + 1832
28  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8b4c35c9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff95093232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8e847a6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9509294a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c92740d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9509294a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c92740d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9509294a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c92740d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9509294a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8c92740d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000002  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x00007fff560ea000  rsi: 0x00007fff99c1d0eb  rbp: 0x00007fff560e8248  rsp: 0x00007fff560e8238
   r8: 0x00007febf1446540   r9: 0x00027ffd3ed0a7e0  r10: 0xffffffffffffffff  r11: 0xffffffec9d852c23
  r12: 0x000000000cc01a00  r13: 0x00007febf393b270  r14: 0x00007fff560e8c60  r15: 0x00007febf28c831c
  rip: 0x00007fff8b87b670  rfl: 0x0000000000010283  cr2: 0x00007fff560ea000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14
```

Comment: Rather than posting a screenshot that only shows a portion of the crash report, how about you copy the ***text*** from the crash report and paste that into your question?

Comment: There are other possible solutions on StackOverflow (like http://stackoverflow.com/q/21203567/558933) - you'll have to try them all until you find one that works as the screenshot doesn't have any useful info that I can see. Also, try "Repair Disk" in the "Disk Utility" - just in case.

Comment: @KenThomases: I did try doing that when posting my question. It wouldn't let me post the entire crash report, as it contained about 66422 characters, while the body allows only 30000 characters. But I've still included some of the crash report this time.

Comment: Have you tried throwing it out and re-downloading it from the AppStore? It looks like it's having trouble parsing a .plist file, possible one in the app's bundle.

Comment: Yes, I've downloaded, deleted, restarted the mac and downloaded again - 3 times. Each time it gives the same crash report. I've looked in the `~/Library/Preferences` folder, there's nothing related to Xcode in it. I've also searched in `~/Library/Saved Application State`, there's no trace of any Xcode element in there as well.